# Matplotlib Line graph line don't stretch to ending grid line

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, charts

[image: My line graph]

My Line graph dosen't stretch to the end of the border but instead starts delayed and ends before the terminating grid line. I have researched this problem but haven't gotten an answer. The following is the code for my chart:

```
plt.style.use("custom_style.mplstyle")
fig     = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=240)
ax      = fig.add_subplot(1, 7, (1, 6))
table   = fig.add_subplot(1, 7, 7)

# Delete the grid lines from the table column
table = plt.gca()
table.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
table.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.box(on=None)

# Create and scale table
CellColor = []
[CellColor.append(["#FFFFFF07"]) for row in range(stats.shape[0])]
theTable = table.table(cellText=stats.values, cellColours=CellColor, loc="center", cellLoc="left")
theTable.scale(1.4, 6)
theTable.set_fontsize(20)

color = "#52cc00" if float(dif) >= 0 else "#cc5240"
ax.plot_date(df["time"], df["close"], fmt=color, xdate=False, marker=None, linewidth=3, linestyle="-")

dateFMT = mdates.DateFormatter(r'%I%p')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dateFMT)
chart_name = name if isinstance(chart_name, pd.core.series.Series) else chart_name
ax.set_title(f"{chart_name}: {close} [{dif}%]", loc="left")

plt.savefig(f"charts/{name}.png")
```

where the contents of custom_style.mplstyle are

```
### FONT
text.color : white
font.family : Tahoma

### AXES
axes.facecolor      : FFFFFF07   # axes background color
axes.edgecolor      : FFFFFF3D   # axes edge color
axes.labelcolor     : FFFFFFD9

### TICKS
xtick.color          : FFFFFFD9      # color of the tick labels
ytick.color          : FFFFFFD9      # color of the tick labels

### GRIDS
grid.color       :   E6E6FA   # grid color
axes.grid : True
grid.linewidth : 0.4

### Legend
legend.facecolor     : inherit   # legend background color (when 'inherit' uses axes.facecolor)
legend.edgecolor : FFFFFFD9 # legend edge color (when 'inherit' uses axes.edgecolor)

### FIGURE
#TODO: notebook ignores this
figure.facecolor : 0C1C23    # figure facecolor
savefig.facecolor : 0C1C23    # figure facecolor
axes.titlepad : 12

### Title
axes.titlesize     : 25
axes.titlelocation : left
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `x` margins to `0` with `plt.margins(x=0)`:

```py
L1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

plt.plot(L1) # Default margins
plt.show()
plt.plot(L1)
plt.margins(x=0) # 0 Margins
plt.show()
```

- Default:
  [image]
- 0 X margin:
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

This delay is caused by the `x` and `y` margins that are non zero by default. Adding up on other answers, you can set this up directly in the `custom_style.mplstyle` file with

```
axes.xmargin: 0
axes.ymargin: 0
```

I here reproduced your case with taking fake data on approximately the same time span and leading to the above image.

[image: custom matplotlib style without axes margins]

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use("custom_style.mplstyle")

# Figure and axes instance
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=240)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 7, (1, 6))
table = fig.add_subplot(1, 7, 7)

# Delete the grid lines from the table column
table = plt.gca()
table.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
table.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.box(on=None)

# Plot
color = "#52cc00"
dates = np.arange(
    np.datetime64("2022-01-01 09:00"), np.datetime64("2022-01-01 11:00")
)
data = np.random.rand(len(dates))
ax.plot_date(
    dates, data, fmt=color, xdate=False, marker=None, linewidth=3, linestyle="-"
)

# Format dates
dateFMT = mdates.DateFormatter(r"%I%p")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dateFMT)
```